# Can websites tell what other programs you are running?

Tags: web

Suppose I have a file open in a word processor or a pdf open in a PDF viewer
while I'm viewing a website. Can the website tell that I have a word processor or PDF viewer open, and can it tell what the name of the file is?

Answer (score 1):

No. Take a look at this question about what data is send from a Browser to websites: https://superuser.com/questions/206164/what-hardware-information-about-your-pcs-can-gathered-by-websites-isps

But it may be possible, when a website asks for control of your webcam, you allow it and place a mirror behind you so that the webcam can film your screen.

Click here to test what data your browser sends to websites: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Have Fun.

Btw.: Your question is not related to programming and therefore offtopic. It might be removed soon.